# jQuery Mobile and Textpattern - Comment form

Tags: jquery-mobile, textpattern

I'm working with the textpattern commenting system using the jQuery Mobile framework.
At the moment when loading the individual article page "http://www.elisabettaclaudio.com/maestro-conte" the form in the popup won't let me post the preview.

Instead the form works when getting to the article page, let's say from this URL "http://www.elisabettaclaudio.com/oh-my-blog" and then go the "http://www.elisabettaclaudio.com/maestro-conte" and I'm able to post the preview.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: can you post your JS code?

Comment: There's no JS code controlling the form at the moment other than jQuery Mobile.

Comment: JQM code is what I meant :)

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but I suspect Textpattern is checking the value of the submit button clicked to determine what to do, but jQuery removes this when handling a form submission.